# How to write multi condition SSN regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to obscure when a social security number is submitted through a part of our application.  The conditions we're being told to check for are if the SSN is sent over as 123-45-6789 or 123 45 6789 (just looking for 3 (space or dash) 2 digits (space or dash) 3 digits.

What I have so far:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}");

var replacement = regex.Replace(comments, "SSN Hidden");
```

So I know the regex is close, but incorrect, for dashes and I need help figuring out how to incorporate spaces as well.  New to regex, thanks in advance.

Comment: Something like `@"\d{3}([- ])\d{2}\1\d{4}"`

Comment: Perfekcyjnie, dziękuję

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```
var replacement = Regex.Replace(comments, @"\d{3}([- ])\d{2}\1\d{4}", "SSN Hidden");
```

Consider using [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) `\b` around the pattern (`@"\b\d{3}([- ])\d{2}\1\d{4}\b"`) if you need to match these numbers as whole words. Or, use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure there are no other digits on both ends: `@"(?<!\d)\d{3}([- ])\d{2}\1\d{4}(?!\d)"`.

To make `\d` only match ASCII digits, consider passing the [`RegexOptions.ECMAScript` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions?view=netframework-4.8).

**Details**

- `\d{3}`  - three digits
- `([- ])` - [Capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) 1: a space or `-`
- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `\1` - a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to Group 1 value (so, it is either `-` or space)
- `\d{4}` - four digits.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cd%7B3%7D%28%5B-%20%5D%29%5Cd%7B2%7D%5C1%5Cd%7B4%7D&i=123-45-6789%20or%20123%2045%206789&o=e).